# Call obj-c class function from another class

Tags: iphone

Im new to Obj-C, and I have a class, with a variable of a class in it, and I have a function not in a class that I need to call a function of the variable of the first one from, when the first class calls the function.  Thats written all wrong, but I dont know the right words so:

Root.h:

```
@interface Root {
    UITableView *tableview;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tableview;
@end
```

I have a function(Root is a delagate, so it gets called, and calls another function, not in any class or anything:

```
void Search()
{
    //here I need to call a function, I dont know how.  If I was in Root.m, it would be
    //[self.tableview reloadData];
```

But here I dont know how to call it, ive tried passing Search a pointer to a function in Root.m that calls the function:

```
-(void) update {
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
-(void) anotherFunction {
    Search(update);
```

or

```
    Search(self.update);
```

etc
but it always errors there, I also tried passing a pointer (self) to Search, and calling

```
[pointer.tableview reloadData];
```

but that errors when I run it:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3detc
```

How Do I do it?

(sorry if this was very confusing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me get this straight: you have a class `Root` and an instance of that class `myRoot`. In the class, there two functions `-update` and `-anotherFunction`. You also have a C function  `search()`. When in `-anotherFunction`, you want to call `search()` and, from there, call back to `-update` in the original instance of `root`.

If that is all correct, let's pretend you got into `-anotherFunction` by calling `[myRoot anotherFunction];`. We'll also assume that everything is in the same file or that all files have been `#import`ed or `#include`d correctly.

You need to define `search()` as `void search(id callback)`. In `-anotherFunction` call `search()` like this: `search(self)`. Then, in `search()`, you can call `[callback update];` to call `-update` from the class instance where you were originally executing `-anotherFunction`.

I think that answers your question. Please don't hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but if you want to call a function defined in a class from outside the class you simply create an instance of the class if its an instance method and use that as the receiver, or if it's a class method, you use the class itself as the receiver.  In other words suppose I want to call the method someFunction which is an instance method of SomeClass.  Here's what I need to do:

```
SomeClass *someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
[someClass someFunction];
```

If it's a class function, I don't need to instantiate an object instance.  I simply do this:

```
[SomeClass someFunction];
```

Comment: Yes. but wouldnt that create another instance of that class?  That doesnt work, and gives the same error as passing a pointer to the class.

Comment: Also your Search method appears to be in C instead of Obj-C.  ALthough this is certainly acceptable, is there any reason not to code it as Objective C?

Comment: I dont like Obj-c, but mostly its because the search method is supposed to be cross platform, and I dont want to have to rewrite it if a platform doesnt support obj-c.  Its declared in a mm file anyway, though, since otherwise it wont compile.

Comment: post the whole file or files.  If you import the file containing Search, you shouldn't have a problem.